# Wrong or merely redundant use of 们?

Tags: grammar

There appear to be some rare examples of suffix 们 after 许多、很多、各位。According to some sources this is acceptable。Examples: 许多:  "许多思想家们认为"(   http://chinese.irib.ir/2010-07-31-13-14-51/2010-07-31-13-16-24/item/47176-%E8%A5%BF%E6%96%B9%E9%81%93%E5%BE%B7%E8%A7%82%E5%BF%B5%E7%BC%BA%E5%A4%B1)  "许多 蜜蜂们" (http://www.ruiwen.com/news/54481.htm) (already questioned at this and other sites)
很多："吸引很多玩家们的参与" (http://www.ezu88.com/4578.html) 各位："这样子 你通知各位兄弟们"(功勋03 ３２：５1,
http://www.le.com/ptv/vplay/25045964.html#vid=25045964)

Comment: It's ungrammatical but accepted in spoken language.

Comment: I think it is not wrong, but redundant.

Comment: 2 more examples for ＂那些。。。们＂ from ＜功勋＞电视剧: 0４，３８：２８：你那些弟兄们能不能喝上棒子面
（http://www.le.com/ptv/vplay/25046084.html#vid=25046084）（wrong use of 们 may be due to the fact that speaker 崔老拐 shortly before has used 弟兄们 correctly w／o preceding indefinite quantifier 些 and by simple inertia got carried away into repeating it with preceding ＂那些＂。（错误使用＂们＂的原因很可能是因为崔老拐在没有表示不定数量词的情况下，数次正确地使用了＂们＂，而接着由于惯性的原因用＂那些＂修饰的时候再次说了＂弟兄们＂）, 05，０８：５１：老六回答崔老拐说：你想让那些跟着你的兄弟们 ０８：５２ 喝西北风啊
（http://www.le.com/ptv/vplay/25046295.html#vid=25046295） It may be noted that the speakers are natives of 满洲的长春 (新京)

Comment: as web searches confirm, redundant use of 们 has been discussed on the web repeatedly (including use with non-human nouns), also as noted in CCG, it regularly occurs as a term of address in gatherings, as others have noted it may have an emotional tinge, implying empathy, (note above use with 弟兄）。

Answer (score 2):

I agree it's redundant. When there's a quantifier following with a noun, never use 们.

们【助】
用在代词或指人的名词后面,表示复数。如:孩子们

**注意：名词前有数量词时，后面不加“们”，例如不说“三个孩子们”**
(http://xuexi.123cha.com/zd/11586.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that 们 in this context is redundant. 许多 and 各位 have already implied that there is more than one entity. Therefore, the 们 here is simply redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It could be redundant, but it's not incorrect. There is no plural in Chinese. At times, having 们 merely makes it sound better.